# 'Missing Operating System' Windows USB on Ubuntu Machine

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, liveusb, usb-boot

So I created a Windows 7 Bootable USB on Ubuntu using 'YUMI' The USB was formatted to NTFS and ISO loaded on using Yumi. I am able to see all the files on there on the Ubuntu Explorer however when trying to boot from USB at boot I just get a quick message saying 'Missing Operating System' then it carries on booting into Ubuntu....

I've tried formatting the drive as both FAT32 & NTFS.

Help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rufus to create the bootable stick. That is easy and works.

http://rufus.akeo.ie/